# How to declare a generic conversion operator that preserves units of measure?

Tags: f#

The built-in conversion operators in F# eliminate units of measure. I'd like to define ones that preserve them. I can do it fine for one specific conversion, e.g. int to float:

```
let inline intToFloat (x:int<'u>) =
    x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>
```

But I don't know what would be the syntax for a generic ((anything with an op_Implicit ^m -> float) -> float) operator:

```
let inline floatM (x:^m<'u>) =
    x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>
// FS0712: Type parameter cannot be used as type constructor
```

Is it possible at all to do this?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, because F# type system can't express higher kinded types.

Comment: I don't use units of measure anymore. The meta reason that as F# lacks HKTs its hard to wok with them. A concrete example that I run into was that some time ago I tried to model currencies with units. That resulted in some serious bloated code on the call site of my library as I had to instantiate types and code for each of the units. I switched to DUs then. Has some other drawbacks but was easier after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to use overloading rather than generics:

```
type Conv =
    static member inline toDouble<[<Measure>] 'u> (x: float32<'u>) = 
        x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>

    static member inline toDouble<[<Measure>] 'u> (x: sbyte<'u>) = 
        x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>

    static member inline toDouble<[<Measure>] 'u> (x: int16<'u>) = 
        x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>

    static member inline toDouble<[<Measure>] 'u> (x: int<'u>) = 
        x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>

    static member inline toDouble<[<Measure>] 'u> (x: int64<'u>) = 
        x |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>
```

And now:

```
let f = Conv.toDouble (45<second>) // f is a float<second>
```

I'd love to be able to declare an operator to hide away the static class, something like:

```
let inline floatM< ^m, [<Measure>]'u when (^m) : (static member toFloat: ^m<'u> -> float<'u>)> (x:^m) =
    Conv.toDouble x
```

But that still runs into the same limitation that a generic type cannot have a generic unit of measure.

I'll accept my own answer until someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did it as such:

```
let inline toIntWithMeasure<[<Measure>] 'a> (x:obj) =
  match x with
  | :? int as i -> i |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'a>
  | _ -> failwith "Not an int!"
```